# How to set multiple select otion values from json

Tags: html, jquery, json

being a begginer in Web Development Im just asking a question about set multiple select option from json using jquery:
Here is my select(s)

**First one is color**

`<select name="attr[]" class="form-control" id="attrColor"><option value="0">--Select</option><option value="1">Red</option><option value="2">Green</option><option value="3">Yellow</option></select>`

**Second one is Size**

`<select name="attr[]" class="form-control" id="attrSize"><option value="0">--Select</option><option value="4">Small</option><option value="5">Medium</option><option value="6">Large</option></select>`

JSON data is hereunder:-
 `[{"attribute":"Color","valueID":"1","value":"Red"},{"attribute":"Size","valueID":"4","value":"Small"}]`

I just need a code snippet to set Color in #attrColor and set Size in #attrSize, both select are in same page and same container.

I shall be very thankful and obliged. Thank you

Im a begginer and i just trying to someone help me